# How to replace specific column values in data frame based on row index?

Tags: r, tidyverse, rename

I have been searching for about an hour for the answer here, so I'm sorry if this is a repeat. I have only found something similar in python.

I have the current data frame and I want to replace the `Subject` numbers from `session 1` from this alternating 1/2 to a sequence of numbers 1 thru 15, similar to `session 2` below.

```
session Subject    Ep.1.    Ep.2.    Ep.3.    Ep.4.    Ep.5.    Ep.6.    Ep.7.    Ep.8.    Ep.9.   Ep.10.   Ep.11.   Ep.12. Ep.13.
1        1       1 2,00E+07 3,00E+07 1,00E+07  1.5e+07 8,00E+06 4,00E+05    20000    50000 1,00E+07 2,00E+07    60000 5,00E+05     60
1        2       2  2.4e+07  3.5e+07  2.3e+07  1.3e+07 1,00E+07 7,00E+06 5,00E+05 8,00E+05 2,00E+06 2,00E+07    30000     5000     35
1        1       3 2,00E+06  1500000 1,00E+06 2,00E+05 1,00E+05 1,00E+07 5,00E+05 5,00E+06 5,00E+08 3,00E+05      600     1000     38
1        2       4 8,00E+06  1.4e+07  1.3e+07  2500000  1500000 3,00E+06 4,00E+05 2,00E+05 2,00E+07 2,00E+07    25000 1,00E+06     70
1        1       5 5,00E+06 1,00E+08 1,00E+06  1.5e+07 1,00E+05 5,00E+06 5,00E+05     1000 1,00E+06 3,00E+07     6000      400     60
1        2       6 5,00E+08 5,00E+08 5,00E+06 1,00E+07 4,00E+05 1,00E+06 1,00E+05 2,00E+05 5,00E+08 8,00E+05     1200    30000     50
1        1       7  1.8e+07 2,00E+07 1,00E+07 1,00E+07 8,00E+06 3,00E+06 6,00E+06 1,00E+05 2,00E+05 5,00E+06     5000     8000     50
1        2       8 3,00E+07  1.8e+07  1.7e+07  2.2e+07 7,00E+06 5,00E+06 3,00E+06 1,00E+08 2,00E+08 1,00E+07    10000 1,00E+06     50
1        1       9 6,00E+05 4,00E+05   250000 3,00E+05   350000 5,00E+05   150000    20000    30000 1,00E+05     1000    10000     35
1        2      10  2.8e+07 4,00E+07  2.5e+07  2.8e+07 5,00E+06  1500000    50000 5,00E+06 1,00E+08 9,00E+07     1000 3,00E+05     32
1        1      11  3.2e+07 30500000  9800000  2.3e+07  1100000  3500000  2750000    23000 7,00E+06  1.2e+07    28000 9,00E+05     50
1        2      12 9,00E+07  2.3e+08 2,00E+06 1,00E+08 7,00E+06 7,00E+06   350000 4,00E+07 3,00E+06 6,00E+07    10000    80000     40
1        2       1 3,00E+07  2.5e+07 2,00E+07  2.5e+07 9,00E+06  1.3e+07 1,00E+07    20000 3,00E+06 2,00E+07    40000    50000     40
1        2       2 4,00E+07 6,00E+07 6,00E+05 2,00E+08 6,00E+06 2,00E+06    40000 1,00E+05    10000 5,00E+05 5,00E+05    10000     35
1        1       3  2.7e+07  2.5e+07  8500000  1.2e+07  3500000  1.1e+07 5,00E+05   123000 5,00E+06 1,00E+06    85000    20000     62
2        1       4  2.5e+07 3,00E+07  2.5e+07  3.5e+07  1.6e+07 2,00E+07 3,00E+06 7,00E+05 5,00E+08 1,00E+07    80000 1,00E+06     35
2        2       5  2.5e+07  1.8e+07  1.2e+07 8,00E+06  5500000 2,00E+06 8,00E+05    42000 8,00E+06 4,00E+06     8000    60000     60
2        3       6 4,00E+08 5,00E+08 2,00E+08  2500000  1500000  1800000 1,00E+05     8000 1,00E+07 5,00E+08      500    10000     50
2        4       7  1.2e+07  1.2e+07 2,00E+06  2.5e+07 3,00E+06 2,00E+06 5,00E+06 1,00E+05 5,00E+05 1,00E+07 2,00E+05    30000     31
2        5       8  2.2e+07  1.2e+09  2500000  8.5e+08 3,00E+07  3500000    23000   240000 2,00E+05 2,00E+05 3,00E+05 1,00E+05     20
2        6       9  1.5e+07 5,00E+06  2500000 1,00E+07 5,00E+06  1500000 2,00E+06 4,00E+08 2,00E+05 2,00E+06    30000    10000     30
2        7      10  3.2e+07  2.5e+07 1,00E+07  2.2e+07 6,00E+06 3,00E+06 1,00E+06    10000 5,00E+07 1,00E+08    36000    50000     37
2        8      11 8,00E+07 8,00E+08 2,00E+07 4,00E+07 1,00E+07  1.2e+07 3,00E+06 5,00E+05 1,00E+07  3.5e+07     4000    10000     65
2        9       1 6,00E+06 2,00E+06 9,00E+05 4,00E+06 5,00E+06 7,00E+05 2,00E+05 1,00E+06 1,00E+05 1,00E+08    10000    10000     45
2        10      2 3,00E+07  2.5e+07 2,00E+06  1.7e+07  1.5e+07  1.4e+07 8,00E+06 1,00E+06 1,00E+08 2,00E+07 5,00E+05 3,00E+06     46
2        11      3  1.2e+07 5,00E+07 2,00E+07 5,00E+07 6,00E+07 2,00E+06 5,00E+07 5,00E+06 5,00E+07 4,00E+06    25000      500     50
2        12      4  4.5e+07  2.4e+07  1.2e+07 2,00E+07 6,00E+06  4.5e+07 9,00E+05    38000 6,00E+05 2,00E+06     2000     7000     42
```

- I can't figure out how to rename these values without also renaming the 1s and 2s from other sessions. I only want the numbers from `session 1` to change into a sequence (1-15)
- I thought about renaming them by their row index numbers, but I have not found any help in my search on how to do that. **Any advice? Is there a way to do this with Tidyverse?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, assuming your data frame is named `dat`:

```
dat$Subject[which(dat$session == 1)] <- seq_along(dat$Subject[which(dat$session == 1)])
```

Comment: Yes that does what I want, thank you! However when I am trying to change my dataframe to incorporate this change, it replaces my entire data frame with just numbers 1-17. I did `dat <- dat$Subject[which(dat$session == 1)] <- seq_along(dat$Subject[which(dat$session == 1)])` and also tried with `dat$Subject` which I guess is wrong

Comment: @dampfy If you had done `dat <- seq_along(dat$Subject[which(dat$session == 1)])`, that would be the result, but the above should just replace the relevant values of Subject without overwriting anything else in the data frame.

Comment: You're right, I placed it after I renamed the column by accident. Problem solved. Thank you so much!